# How to Sign .exe using .crt or .cer file. I ONLY have .crt and .cer files issued by Comodo

Tags: certificate, inno-setup, setup-deployment, code-signing-certificate

I ONLY have .crt file with me which I purchased from Comodo. No private key or any thing. How can I use this to sign my code and get rid of "publisher unknown" issue in my installer. I have used Inno-Setup for creating the installer too. Code is in C Sharp. I tried to use sign tool and openssl but I don't have any other file than this user.crt file. I just can get .cer format using .crt and thats all.  Appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot sign files with a public key only.

You need the private key.

If it were possible to sign files with a public key only, anyone could sign malicious content with your public key.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I made it using the pfx file and the issue is solved.Was a newbie

Comment: How did you use a pfx file to solve the issue? All I got from Comodo as well was "user.crt" with no instructions, confirmed it is a public key.

Comment: Part 1 - About Comodo Code Signing Certificate - user.crt is not what you need to sign the your exe. You have to collect your certificate in the browser and then to export it , I have used Firefox browser (Chorme is not supported, this is why you get the public user.crt downloaded). When you get the link from Comodo to collect your certificate, you will get a message similar to this - "your certificate was installed".

Comment: Part 2 - Then go in Firefox's settings / Manage Certificate / Your certificates. You will se your new certificate, now just export it (you will have to set password). Better you KSign tool instead of signtool, it's easier.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, you need sign the application from PC where you are registered Comodo certificate. The private key saved by your browser in the local storage.

Comment: You neet export the private key from certmgr.msc and apply it in your host.

Comment: Rad87 Yes now I'm aware of it. Thanks for the info. I have signed the exe using the pfx file which I was unable to find earlier.

Comment: Please explain how to export private key